# Laravel 5 - Redirecting a user to a specific page based on their role on authentication

Tags: php, laravel

I am using the [Bican Roles](https://github.com/romanbican/roles) package with Laravel 5 and i'm trying to figure out how to modify the AuthController class to redirect a user to their designated page based on their role. I read on an article somewhere that i would need to create the method authenticate to override the default function but i'm unsure how i would include all the methods of the bican class. For example on the github page of bicon it says to use

$user->level to get the users level but i get an error,

```
protected function authenticated($user)
    {
        dd($user->level);
    }
```

Comment: Please post your error along with the question so we can see what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem:

1. You can create [the middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware) to checking user's role on specific routes.
2. On your method `authenticated()`, variable `$users` is not defined. Documentation of `bican/roles` package uses shorthand of `Auth::user()` to get data of current user. So you should use:

   ```
   Auth::user()->is('YOUR_ROLE_NAME');          # To check user role
   Auth::user()->can('YOUR.ACTION');            # To check user permission
   Auth::user()->level();                       # To check user level  
   Auth::user()->allowed('ACTION', $someModel); # To check user permission to object
   ```

> I read on an article somewhere that i would need to create the method authenticate to override the default function

Until that default function is in `app` directory, it pass. But Laravel controllers are so flexible that you can do it in another ways (*look first point*).